# IIS 7 Hosting multiple sites with HTTPS bindings. How do I setup new IP address in Windows 7/IIS 7

Tags: windows-7, iis-7, https

I need to host two HTTPS sites in IIS for development so I need to assign one of the sites to another IP address so they both work.

What are the steps for doing this in IIS 7 and Windows 7? How do I pick an appropriate IP address?

Comment: Is the IP address already assigned to the machine?

Comment: No it isn't. Starting from the beginning!

Answer (score 2):

### To Assign More Than One IP to the Same NIC in Windows 7

1. Go to **Control Panel > Network and Internet > Network Connections**
2. *Right* click on **Local Area Connection** and select **Properties**
3. Select **Internet Protocol Version 4 (TCP/IPv4)** and click **Properties**
4. **Turn off DHCP** by setting the IP, subnet mask , and default gateway.
   I would also suggest setting your DNS servers.
5. Click on the **Advanded** button below where you set the DNS servers.
6. The IP address that you just set should show up in the new window that you just opened by clicking **Advanced**.
7. To add a *second* IP address, click on the **Add** button and add the IP
   and subnet mask.
8. OK out of everything.
9. Open the command prompt and type `ipconfig /all` and make sure it's
   showing *both* IP addresses.

If it's not showing both, you may need to restart your network connection (`ipconfig /release` and `ipconfig /renew`) to get things working.

For a visual guide, look [HERE](http://www.windowsreference.com/windows-2000/how-to-addassign-multiple-ip-address-in-vistaxp20002003/). This is for Windows XP, but you basically follow the same steps.

### To Assign the IPs in IIS.

1. Open IIS Manager
2. Expand **Sites**
3. Right click on the site you want to assign and select **Edit Bindings**
4. If `https` is *not* there, click **Add** and select **https** as the type and select the appropriate specific IP address.
5. If `https` *is* there, click on it and select **Edit**, and assign it to the appropriate IP
       address.

***Note that you must have separate IP addresses for each site for SSL to work properly in IIS unless you are using a wildcard certificate.*

Comment: Yup, I am aware of that. This doesn't work off the bat. What do I need to do in Windows to configure that IP address?

Comment: You need to clarify your question, then, to specify what you need specifically.

Comment: I said in IIS 7 and Windows 7. I wouldn't assume I have carried out any steps. I also ask how to pick an appropriate IP address which suggests I have not configured it yet.

Comment: SSL-enabled sites can share the same IP address provided that they share the same SSL certificate that covers all host headers (a wildcard certificate, for example)

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that, Chris. Totally forgot to mention wildcard certs.